# mv/cp commands not working as expected wih xargs in bash

Tags: bash, sh, xargs, cp, mv

Hi I have 2 parent directories with these contents, under /tmp:

[image: directories]

Note parent directory names have ";" in it- not recommended in Unix like systems, but those directories are pushed by an external application, and that's the way we have to deal with it.

I need to move these parent directories (along with their contents) to /tmp/archive - on a RHEL 7.9 (Maipo) machine

My simple code:

```
ARCHIVE="/tmp/archive"
[ -d "${ARCHIVE}" ] && mkdir -p "${ARCHIVE}"
ls -lrth /tmp | awk "\$NF ~ /2021-.*/{print \$NF}" | xargs -I "{}" mv "{}" ${ARCHIVE}/
```

But when I run this script, `mv` copies one of the parent directory as it is, but for the other one, it just moves the contents of the parent directory, not the directory itself:

[image]

I tried the same script with `cp -pvr` command in place of `mv`, and its the same behavior
[image]

When I run the same script in a `Ubuntu 18` system, the behavior is as expected i.e - the parent directories get moved to archive folder.

[image: Step-1]

[image: Step-2]

[image: Step-3]

[image: Step-4]

Why is there this difference in behavior between a `Ubuntu` and a `RHEL` system, for the same script

Comment: Please replace all images with its text.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Talk to the provider of the external application and explain to them that including `';'` ins the file and directory names is batsh.t crazy and complicates file handling to no end. At least spaces have no special meaning to a Unix shell beyond providing a place for most shells to word-split. You will have to escape the `';'`every place you handle the names  to ensure they are not interpreted by the shell. It really is a bad idea (as you know). The provider should know better than to dump raw database records as directory names.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler approach:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/archive
mv -v /tmp/2021-*\;*\;*/ /tmp/archive
```